# I need to calculate the average of the return of daily prices with lag 6 days Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe with dates and stock prices. I need to calculate the average of return but with a lag of 2 days.

For example,

[image]

I need to get the average( (67.4/55.1)-1 & (78/96.1)-1... & (12.1/17.3)-1) for each identifier and add it to a new dataframe.

I cant find an easy way to do it, so I would appreciate your suggestions!
I tried copying from my excel the dummy dataframe here but it doesnt work. So unfortunately, i added it as an image. If you suggest as well a way to paste the dataframe as text in stackexchage, this would be fab.

I am expecting the below

[image]
Thanks all!

Comment: can you pls show what you expect.

Comment: On SO its encouraged to post samples in form of text, kindly do edit your question with text samples in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: @sadbro I added what i expect

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I tried to put the table after 4 spaces but again it shows as messed up values... I am new here but I dont understand how you guys do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can create a function to get both days 6 dates apart for a certain date and use dataframe manipulation to get both values and average them.
the pseudo-code may be something like this:

df_dict = the dictionary of dataframe
def getdates(date):
while date in df_dict.keys():
return date, date +6

use a list parser on df_dict to get positions on all keys and then use that to parse on every 2 keys and get their values and then use a avg function and calculate and store the result in a array which later you add to df

Comment: I found this solution, just the usual .pct_change() and add the freq='6'

Answer (score 0):

The parameter freq can be handy using .pct_change(). so for 6 business days lag --> .pct_change(freq='6b')